# Define a range to output query result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm performing a query against a `sheet`, which returns the values in a specific `row`. By default, the formula outputs the result in a `row` with the same number of `columns`. **I want to be able to output all the results in a `column`.**

**For Example**

Data where query is performed

```
      |Column A|Column B|Column C|
_____
Row 1  value A   Value B  Value C
```

Way query result needs to be displayed

```
      |Column A|Column B|Column C|
_____
Row 1  value A     
_____
Row 2  Value B
_____
Row 3  Value C
```

Comment: Transpose it? `=transpose(query())`

Comment: What's the point of columns b and c in your desired result? Waste space?